# Cppcheck Jenkins plugin not expanding variables

Tags: c++, jenkins, cppcheck

I have a Jenkins job that creates a cppcheck XML report. I need to publish this report into Jenkins.

**This works:**
[image]

**This does NOT work:**
[image]

So it seems to me that Jenkins is not correctly expanding environment variables in that specific case. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: No, I didn't. Jenkins is pretty messy in practice so I decided to move to another solution.

Comment: File a Bug here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+JENKINS+AND+status+in+%28Open%2C+%22In+Progress%22%2C+Reopened%29+AND+component+%3D+%27cppcheck%27

Answer (score 0):

Its a little late, but if you were using pipelines and had `Lightweight checkout` selected, your variables will **NOT** expand...